# DATEDIFF() Excluding Marked Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to see how many days there are between two dates excluding certain dates that depend on a value stated in another table.

table1

```
ID    in_date      out_date
001   01/01/2017   01/05/2017
002   01/03/2017   01/05/2017
```

For example:

```
SELECT 
   id
  ,datediff(dd, t1.in_date, t1.out_date) as diff
FROM table1 t1
```

Would bring

```
ID    diff
001   4
002   2
```

But let's say I have another table:

table2

```
date         use
01/01/2017   Y
01/02/2017   N
01/03/2017   N
01/04/2017   Y
01/05/2017   Y
```

And I want to see the datediff between dates that have Y under column `use`.

So the result when joining table 1 and 2 should pull:

```
ID    diff
001   3
002   2
```

- Is that a case statement?
- How would I use in the above example in table one? Would I join based on date?

Comment: datediff(month,in_date,out_date)

Comment: Will `table2` _always_ contain an entry for _every_ date between the minimum and maximum dates in `table1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think of something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t2.cnt as diff
FROM table1 t1 outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from table2 t2
      where t2.date >= t1.in_date and t2.date <= t1.out_date and t2.use = 'Y'
     ) t2;
```

That is count the matching days and dispense with the `datediff()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `left join` based on the dates:

```
select t.id, count(t2.date) as diff
from table1 as t
  left join table2 as t2
    on t2.date >= t.in_date
   and t2.date <= t.out_date
   and t2.[use] = 'Y'
group by t.id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XNX74966

returns:

```
+-----+------+
| id  | diff |
+-----+------+
| 001 |    3 |
| 002 |    2 |
+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the use case to be :
- to determine the number of working dates between two given dates.
i.e. table2 contains all the holidays.
If my assumption is right, then its optimal to store only the holidays and weekends in table2. i.e. there would be no need of entries with [use]='N' in table2.
Proceeding under that assumption, here is what I would do:

```
 Create function dbo.GetHolidayCount(@indate datetime, @outdate datetime)
    returns int as
    Begin
    Declare @cnt int = 0
    Select @cnt = count(*) from table2 where [date] >= @indate and [date] <= @outdate and [use]='N';
    return @cnt
    End
```

Then issue the following query.

```
   SELECT 
   id, 
  ,datediff(dd, t1.in_date, t1.out_date) + 1 - dbo.GetHolidayCount(t1.in_date, t1.out_date) as diff
FROM table1 t1
```

I am adding 1 to the result because datediff between 01/01/2017 and   01/05/2017 would return 4; but you need 5 as per your requirements.